# How to create django model for tenants and properties?

Tags: python, django, django-models

2.2.Property Listing Module

Property Details: Create property profile with information like Property name and address, location, features.
Each property will have multiple units. Each unit will have features like rent cost,Type- 1BHK,2BHK,3BHK,4BHK
property profile view with units and assigned tenant information

2.3.Tenant Management Module

Create a tenant profile with name, address, document proofs.
Assign a tenant with a unit under a property with details like agreement end date, monthly rent date. Need a search based on features added for units and properties.
Show tenant profile view with personal information and rental information

```
from django.db import models

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    features = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "properties"

class Unit(models.Model):

    UNIT_TYPES = [
        ('1BHK', '1BHK'),
        ('2BHK', '2BHK'),
        ('3BHK', '3BHK'),
        ('4BHK', '4BHK'),
    ]
    rent_cost = models.IntegerField()
    unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=UNIT_TYPES)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='units')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.unit_type} unit in {self.property.name}"
    
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
    address=models.TextField()
    document_proofs=models.ImageField()
    assigned_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

This what I developed.Is this correct way of creating model.

how to include agreement end date, monthly rent date in this model